# How I select a specific word in perl using regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I've created a Shell script in Perl that should match the line with `Girone : Girone Rosso` and save just the `Girone Rosso` (that is a variable, so I was thinking to write it like `[a-zA-Z]`).

Here my attempt:

```
pdftotext -layout "$KMVAR_local_PathStr" - \
| perl -wne '
    if ( m!^Girone :\h+.+! ) {
        s!^Girone :\h+!!gm;
        print;
}
'
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to match then match a second time using substitution.

```sh
perl -ne'print if s/^Girone\h*:\h*//'
```

But more general, you are asking how to capture. That's done using parens.

```perl
if ( /^Girone\h*:\h*(.*)/ ) {
   # ... do something with $1 ...
}
```

or

```perl
if ( my ($value) = /^Girone\h*:\h*(.*)/ ) {
   # ... do something with $value ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to replace the part after the match, you can print the match making use of `\K` to clear the match buffer using `^Girone :\h+\K.+` where the part `.+` will match 1+ characters.

```
^Girone :\h+\K.+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kQ2ms8/1)

I am not very experienced with perl, but as an example:

```
my $str = "Girone : Girone Rosso";
if ($str =~ m/^Girone :\h+\K.+/) {
    print $&;
}
```

Output

```
Girone Rosso
```

Comment: the out put is correct but is repeated an indefinite numer of times (like an hundred)

Comment: Do you have a hundred matches? Or are you doing any kind of looping around the matching? How many prints are you expecting?

Comment: I have just one match in the file, the expected print should be one. No loop in matching.

Comment: @RiccardoValenti Do you still get so many output lines? The code does a single check for `$str` against the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your question but if you just want to print out the name whenever it's encountered, you would do this.  You can also use `$.` to print what line it matched on.

```perl
pdftotext -layout "$KMVAR_local_PathStr" - | perl -wne 'm/Girone : (Girone Rosso)/ and print "Line $.: $1\n"; '
```

See the [Perl doc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre) for more info.